# Check if another pipeline exists

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

While I am running a Jenkins pipeline I need to check if there is some other job with a specified name, such as "Build712". How can I do?

Thanks,
Sergio

Comment: by pipeline you mean another build of another job?

Comment: I mean another job

Comment: So do i understand correctly that you want to scan over all the jobs you have to check if any of them have a specific buildname like "Build712" for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check if some buildname is present in any of the jenkins jobs you can write a groovy script:

```
 Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(AbstractItem.class).each {
   jobName=it.fullName.toString()
   if(Hudson.instance.getJob(jobName).getBuildByNumber(10).getProperties()) {
     println(jobName)
   }
 };
```

This would println out all job names that have a buildNumber of 10. This is just an example you can go from here and tweak it to match exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: But I guess you need to approve the script execution in the Jenkins settings "ScriptApproval" which shows a big warning _Approving this signature may introduce a security vulnerability! You are advised to deny it._

Answer (score 1):

one possibility would be to use the [copyArtifacts Plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/copyartifact/) to copy a small/empty file from the other build into your current workspace.

e.g.

```
copyArtifacts projectName: 'MyFolder/My%2FJob/master', target: 'artifacts'
```

Hint: You need to replace spaces with %2F

This command will fail, if the job cannot be found as the *optional* flag is false by default.
You then could either

- use a script block with try-catch
- use the *optional* flag of copyArtifacts and check if the file exists using

  if (!fileExists('result.txt')) {}

I know, that this is a bit of a workaround.

There might be some other option using `Jenkins.getInstance().getItemByFullName()`.

Comment: This does not seem to be a scalable option. If you know the jobs by name and there are 5 jobs you want to scrape then fine but if your jenkins project has 100+ jobs then no way you would be maintaining this hardcoded piece of code :)